# Update the component variable before calling the component in angular4

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my application there is a admin and dashboard page, based on the admin settings dashboard page will appear.

**Scenario:** admin logged into the application and changes the values in admin page then navigating to the dashboard page.

**My approach:** While saving the setting in admin page triggered  the service emit call to the dashboard component and changed the dashboard component variable by using the subscribe.

**Issue:** After the settings changes from admin navigated to dashboard page, but the changes (variable) values are not reflecting.

**My observation :** When we are in admin page dashboard component won't be available in the dom, but due to the service emitter function called the dashboard component subscription and changes the value unfortunately while loading the variable values resetting.

Is there any way to set the component variable before rendering(calling) into the dom? (Except storage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With available statement problem and no code, I could come up only with the following :-

Maintain a simple service storing all the settings of the admin panel.

Whenever a user changes a value in the admin panel, change the value of that variable in the service.

Whenever dashboard gets load (OnInit), bind values in dashboard component from the service to get current admin panel values and display dashboard component accordingly.

You don't need to emit any event since the dashboard component and admin panel doesn't occur at same time in view.Creating a service to maintain the state of admin settings will be fine.Both components can share that service and act accordingly.